# Simulation tool for Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, simulator

Can any body suggest me the best simulation tool now a days for Bluetooth Networks. in order to test various algorithoms about Routing and Roaming issue.

Answer (score 4):

There are two that I know of: [NS-2](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/.) (with the [UCBT: Bluetooth Extension](http://www.ececs.uc.edu/cdmc/ucbt/.)) and [QualNet](http://www.scalable-networks.com/.).  Of those, NS2 is probably the most used.

Answer (score 2):

There is ns3 those ns2 is still the most widely used simulator. The network simulation 2 and 3 are opensource projects with lots of implementations and protocol models already available to you. In such case all you need to do is, write the code of your network setup on a tcl file and execute. Voila, you have ur output on the trace file.

Qualnet is propitiatory and very expensive to license, but is definitely more easy to use. Also the support you get from their team is great.

So if you have the dough to get qualnet, I would recommend that else opensource projects rule... :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible in Matlab to do simulation for Bluetooth algorithoms

Comment: Possible, sure anything is possible if you work hard enough.  Has it been done already?  Not that I know of.