# Network simulation tool supporting Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, simulation, ns2, ns-3

We'd like to perform a Bluetooth network simulation.
As far as we have researched, Bluetooth module has not been implemented in ns-3 and ns-2 modules recommended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994941/bluetooth-simulator-for-ns2) have not been updated for years. We have not found any other simulation tool supporting this protocol apart from [this mention to Qualnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528964/simulation-tool-for-bluetooth), which I have not been able to verify on their website.
Is there any current network simulation tool that includes a Bluetooth module or should we still use ns-2?

Answer (score 1):

All the Bluetooth examples in ns-2.29/ucbt-0.9.8.2a/test/ are working OK :
`$ ns-nist-pmipv6 1f.tcl` etc. etc. 
( Except tcp.tcl, which causes "Segmentation fault", when the old executable 'ns-nist-pmipv6' is used with a contemporary "Linux OS".)

Examples are :

```
1f.tcl        mr5n.tcl       pico-3mb.tcl  scat-form-law.tcl  test_inq.tcl
2sco_inq.tcl  ms5n1.tcl      pico.tcl      tcp.tcl            test_sco.tcl
3f.tcl        ms5n.tcl       rphsi.tcl     tdrp.tcl           test_sdp.tcl
dsdv.tcl      multislot.tcl  rs.tcl        test_fh.tcl        udp.tcl
```

Code : ns-2.29-nist-mob-022707.tgz ( + pmip6-for-ns-2.29-nist.patch )

NIST-MOB info :

. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/nist|sort:date

. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/nist-mob/

The compat-gcc-34-**-3.4.6 compilers from CentOS ( RHEL ) which can compile the old nist-mob code have been repacked to Debian packages. Versions are available for Ubuntu 10.04 + 10.10 and for Ubuntu 11.10 .. 15.04 .