# bluetooth implementation error in tcl

Tags: bluetooth, tcl, ns2

I am implementing wireless technology via bluetooth protocol in N/S2. It is a tcl script. But I am getting the following error:

```
num_nodes is set 4
    (_o13 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o13 cmd rt AODV"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
        set cls [$self info class]
        global errorInfo
        set savedInfo $errorInfo
        error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o13" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$node_($i) rt AODV"
    ("for" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    set node_($i) [$ns_ node $i]
    $node_($i) rt AODV
    $node_($i) on
    [$node_($i) set l2cap_] set ifq_limit_ 30 
    $nod..."
    (file "bluetooth.tcl" line 58)
```

Comment: Unknown ns2 version, unknown file bluetooth.tcl . Unknown "Linux OS". ( ns2 is getting old. Several protocols can no longer be built or used with a contemporary "Linux OS".) Did you add any "bluetooth" to ns2 ? ucbt ?  Your file "bluetooth.tcl" can be uploaded to 'Google Docs'.  Bluetooth examples : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283109/network-simulation-tool-supporting-bluetooth/33287043#33287043

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the implementation of the `rt` method, or at least that that's what is detecting the problem. The _real_ problem might lie elsewhere. (And dear `$env(DEITY)`, looking at that stack trace makes me worry a lot about the implementation of OTcl's internals. It's going to be so _slow_...)

Comment: I am using ubuntu 15.04 and ns2 version is 2.35+dfsg-2ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to see your scenario and give you an answer...Second, it seems that you are trying to create your nodes with another parameter that won't be needed...

Try this :

```
set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
```

Instead of this :

```
set node_($i) [$ns_ node $i]
```

And about the next lines you can do this to find out what you are missing or which parameter you are using the wrong way :

1. Open a new terminal and `cd` to your ns2 directory.

   For example : `$cd /ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/`
2. Use `grep` to find out how to use those parameter, correctly.

   Example :

   ```
   grep -r "rt AODV" ./
   ```

   Or if the result is more that your terminal's history, you can specify a file for your search :

   ```
   grep -r "rt AODV" ./ > search.txt
   ```

Try it for each parameter to find out how does it work.